# why if I put (myVariable += 1) as alrenative to (myVariable++) in (for loop) in javascript generate infinite loop in this code?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, operators

this code is working as I expected to take the input value as parameters for javascript function to generate years selector in html document (the result years in the selector start from  the year you enter in the (from) input field, and end in the year you enter in the (to) input field ) ,

but when I replace **(years++)** with **(years+=1)** **in the for loop** I get infinite loop and the browser stops working!

I also tried (years = years +1), and I also get the same result as above;

I searched for an answer but didn't find something that makes this understandable for me,

thanks in advance.

```js
var fromInput = document.getElementById("fromInput"),
    toInput = document.getElementById("toInput"),
    startY,
    endY;
    
function generateYears(start, end) {
    "use strict";
    
    var years;
    document.write("<select>");
    
    for (years = start; years <= end; years++) {
        
        document.write("<option value= '" + years + "' >" + years + "<option>");
    }
    
    document.write("</select>");
}


function genYe() {
    "use strict";
    startY = fromInput.value;
    endY = toInput.value;
    generateYears(startY, endY);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="description" content="years selector">
     <title>years selector</title>
     
 </head>
 
 <body>
     
     from <input id="fromInput" value=""><br>
     to <input id="toInput" value=""><br><br>
     <button onclick="genYe()">generate years</button>
     
     <script src="mainscript.js"></script> 
     
 </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that the for loop does not support the `+=` or anything like that.

you are initializing the year from a string in statement `years = start;`. here start is a string not an integer returned by the input field.

now when you run `year++` javascript typecasts it automatically to the integer because the string does not operate on a `++` operator.

but in other case like `years += 1` it does not typecast it to integer so `1` is appended to the string and the loop continues.

i.e for first 5 iterations the value of the year will be.

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
```

and each value is string.
so simply typecast the value to integer with `parseInt` before assigning it to the years in for loop.

```js
var fromInput = document.getElementById("fromInput"),
    toInput = document.getElementById("toInput"),
    startY,
    endY;
    
function generateYears(start, end) {
    "use strict";
    
    var years;
    document.write("<select>");
    
    for (years = parseInt(start); years <= end; years += 1) {
        
        document.write("<option value= '" + years + "' >" + years + "<option>");
    }
    
    document.write("</select>");
}


function genYe() {
    "use strict";
    startY = fromInput.value;
    endY = toInput.value;
    generateYears(startY, endY);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="description" content="years selector">
     <title>years selector</title>
     
 </head>
 
 <body>
     
     from <input id="fromInput" value=""><br>
     to <input id="toInput" value=""><br><br>
     <button onclick="genYe()">generate years</button>
     
     <script src="mainscript.js"></script> 
     
 </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this really makes sense!

Answer (score 5):

The `+` operator is used for both string concatenation and addition, depending on the data type of its operands. When you switch to `+=` or `+` you are performing **string concatenation**, not addition, because **the value of `start` (and `year`) is a string**. The `<` operator will compare two strings lexicographically. While it looks like the value becomes "larger", the first character(s) of the string never changes, so the condition will never be true.

```js
var start = '1'
var end = '3'
var year = start;
console.log(typeof year, year, year < end);
console.log(typeof year, year += 1, year < end);
console.log(typeof year, year += 1, year < end);
```

The `++` operator on the other hand always converts the operand to a number:

```js
var start = '1'
var end = '3'
var year = start;
console.log(typeof year, year, year < end);
year++;
console.log(typeof year, year, year < end);
year++;
console.log(typeof year, year, year < end);
```

---

You can fix that be converting your values to numbers first:

```
function genYe() {
    "use strict";
    startY = Number(fromInput.value);
    endY = Number(toInput.value);
    generateYears(startY, endY);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I really appreciate your amazing explanation! :)